# cpufreq not available 11.10

Tags: 11.10, cpufreq, amd-processor

on 11.04 I had cpufreq working on my "AMD Turion(tm) 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-50 stepping 02" processors, however now on oneiric cpufreq won't load.

The core temperature of my cpu is normally 40 c, but lately it's cooking away at 75-80+ c and the fan is always extremely loud even when cpu usage has at 0.4%.

and after this `dmesg | grep -i cpu` I got:

```
Brought up 2 CPUs
Switch to broadcast mode on CPU1
Switch to broadcast mode on CPU0
Switched to NOHz mode on CPU #1
Switched to NOHz mode on CPU #0
ACPI: acpi_idle registered with cpuidle
cpufreq-nforce2: No nForce2 chipset.
cpuidle: using governor ladder
cpuidle: using governor menu
powernow-k8: Found 1 AMD Turion(tm) 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-50 (2 cpu cores) (version 2.20.00)
```

I see something about governors and ladder there, does this mean the OS is able to scale my cpu's or not? If so is there a way I can determine it's working?

I saw that for other users that the wrong module had been loaded and by disabling it they were able to get cpufreq loaded. How can I tell what scaling module is loaded?

stats:
Ubuntu Oneiric 32bit
Dell Inspiron 1501

Answer (score 1):

BIOS settings > enable "Powernow".

I recently had an issue with a faulty USB port so I disabled all the "extra" features on my BIOS so I could really nail down what was failing. When done I forgot to re-enable power management.